# ArcGIS Runtime: application crash when changing parent of MapView

Tags: c#, .net, arcgis, esri

I'm developing with ArcGIS Runtime SDK for dotNet 10.2.6.
(Environment: Win7 64bit, .net 4.5.2, compiled for x86, WPF project)

When I change the parent element (e.g. Grid) of the MapView in my project, the application sometimes just crashes with no exception or message.
This happens after just a few switches between parents.

Is this a known bug ? Any workaround ?

This is the error I see in the Windows Event Viewer:

```
Faulting module name: MSVCR120.dll, version: 12.0.21005.1, time stamp: 0x524f7ce6
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00011703
Faulting process id: 0x1ac4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d147a199237ca7
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS SDKs\DotNet10.2.6\WindowsDesktop\bin\arcgisruntime10.2.6\client32\MSVCR120.dll
```

Comment: I've found Engine/Runtime apps will often crash silently if an uncaught exception is thrown - have you got exception handlers around the relevant code?

Comment: Yes. I have try/catch surrounding this code, and I use the global unhandled exception event: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += UnhandledExceptionHandler;` - no exception is caught.